# Server doesn't receive more than 1 message from client (threaded socket programming)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server

I've just started with socket programming and I'm simply trying to let clients send data to a server over a TCP connection. The server will then forward the data to one fixed client that is simply going to display it.

I thought that this wouldn't be anything too hard. After I set up the server and the client that only displays the sent data, I created multiple clients using PuTTY to send some data to the server, and everything worked out just fine. The server forwarded the messages and the fixed client displayed it. But now that I've coded those "sending clients", I can only get one of those clients to send one single message and after that everything is "stuck". There is no error message or anything. As soon as I send a second message the console doesn't prompt me to give it a third message. I can only close the clients and that's it.

Here's the code for the clients that simply send data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


void main()
{
    std::string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";            
    int port = 54000;                       

    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    char buf[4096];
    std::string userInput;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "> ";
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);

        if (userInput.size() > 0) {     
            int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
            if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "SERVER> " << std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (userInput.size() > 0);

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

This is the code for the client that should just display what has been sent by the other clients:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void main() {

    std::string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1"; 
    int port = 54000;               


    WSAData data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0) {

        std::cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

        std::cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port); 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        std::cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    char buf[4096];

    do {

        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {

            std::cout << "SERVER> " << std::string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << std::endl;
        }
    } while (true);

    closesocket(sock);

    WSACleanup();

}
```

This is the code for the server that should be able to handle several clients:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")


void main()
{
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    fd_set master;
    FD_ZERO(&master);

    FD_SET(listening, &master);

    while (true)
    {
        fd_set copy = master;

        int socketCount = select(0, &copy, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        for (int i = 0; i < socketCount; i++)
        {
            SOCKET sock = copy.fd_array[i];
            if (sock == listening)
            {
                SOCKET client = accept(listening, nullptr, nullptr);

                FD_SET(client, &master);

                std::string joinMsg = "Client joined\r\n";
                send(client, joinMsg.c_str(), joinMsg.size() + 1, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                char buf[4096];
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

                int bytesIn = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesIn <= 0)
                {
                    closesocket(sock);
                    FD_CLR(sock, &master);
                }
                else
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < master.fd_count; i++)
                    {
                        SOCKET outSock = master.fd_array[i];
                        if (outSock != listening && outSock != sock)
                        {
                            send(outSock, buf, bytesIn, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");
}
```

Can someone tell me what I've been missing? I've already spent two days figuring out, what is wrong here.

Comment: What you seem to be missing is setting the correct value for the first parameter to `select()`. You are also missing the ability to know how to use a debugger in order to debug your code. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Could you give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?